# Interactive windows not displaying correctly in R

Tags: r

For a few months I have been encountering an issue on multiple different computers and across different versions of R where none of the interactive windows from the utils package and base R are displaying correctly.

The functions where this occurs is choose.files, askYesNo, and file.choose (first 2 from the Utils package and 3rd is base). The only thing that I have found that works temporarily is to go into C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\ and delete the RStudio folder.

Windows 10
Installed RAM   32.0 GB (31.7 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

RStudio Build: 2023.06.0 Build 421

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32               
arch           x86_64                           
os             mingw32                          
crt            ucrt                             
system         x86_64, mingw32                  
status                                          
major          4                                
minor          3.1                              
year           2023                             
month          06                               
day            16                               
svn rev        84548                            
language       R                                
version.string R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
nickname       Beagle Scouts
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `utils::choose.files()`, `utils::askYesNo("Quaestion")` and other work for me on Windows 10 with the most current R and RStudio versions:

[image]

[image]

So it seems that the issue is specific to your case which makes it more difficult to debug. I have some ideas: try them, and report what works and what does not.

a) What is the working directory in your R session? Does it contain any non-English (i.e., non-ASCII) symbols? If yes, try using ASCII symbols only. Try:

```r
getwd()
```

b) Are there any non-ASCII symbols in your Windows user name (you hid it in your question)? If yes, try some other username (by creating a new user as just renaming will not solve the issue) that contains only ASCII symbols. You may try this code for checking:

```r
 Sys.getenv(c("LOGNAME", "USERNAME", "USERPROFILE", "HOME", "R_USER", "R_HOME", "R_LIBS_USER"))
```

If you discover some question marks in the output, this shows the issue. If question marks are not present, the presence of non-ASCII symbols indicates an issue as well.

c) if the suggestions above do not work (show no issues), try changing all Windows locales and regions to non-English ones and check again. Preferably, change them one by one to locate the exact issue.

D) Lastly, if you installed some packages or software that compete with Tcl/Tk (I cannot recall the exact tools, but I had that experience in the past), these may distort Tcl/Tk installation or setup. I also cannot remember how I solved that.

Yet, firstly check, if there are any issues related to non-English language and non-ASCII symbols as these create many silent issues.